# Does logging into multiple google accounts drain battery/data faster?

Tags: applications, battery, data

I have the Samsung a32 5g.
I'm logged into many G-mail accounts and twitter accounts, will doing so drain my phone battery and data faster simply by having them logged in? Do they do this only if they are running?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others finding for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: This site expects that one question only be asked in a post, not multiple, unless very closely related. You can ask the second part in a separate question //First part, yes multiple accounts mean more battery drain because they have to sync for contacts, calendars, mails, messages etc. They do this when they have data connection, they needn't be running in foreground

Comment: My bad, I'll remove the extra question.

Comment: @beeshyams
What if you don't have sync enabled? Does it still have any affect if you open and use the applications/don't use them?

Comment: You can disable sync for Google accounts to save battery but then you can't use all of them, for instance you need to see new mails and similarly new social media stuff //unless the device is in doze,  apps will be active and consume some battery //you can search for doze on this site or Internet

Comment: See [doze-mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/doze-mode/info) tag info and questions under it

Comment: My phone already does have tools to put apps to sleep similar to greenify. I don't mind not having everything synced, I just wanna know if it will consume more data/battery or not and I'm assuming no based on what you said about sync.